# What is the common practices using GL internal state variable in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I know that when writing GLSL, the shader is able to access those GL internal variables such as

glNormal
gl_NormalMatrix
gl_ModelViewMatrix
gl_Vertex

etc.

as uniform data in the shader.

However, I get into a problem when using those GL internal variables. For example, I assume if my shader need to access the gl_ModelViewMatrix, in my C code, I need to call

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

But it seems that debugger like NVidia NSight didn't like my program calling glMatrixMode(), and gDEDebugger flag this function as a deprecated function. By having this function in my code will make the NSight debugger unable to debug the shader code because it only support openGL 4.x later. Similiar to glNoraml, I assume if I use it in my shader, then I need to call

```
glBegin()
glNormal3f();
glEnd();
```

and I believe the later openGL standard also treat glBegin()/glEnd() as deprecated functions. Then, is n't mean that I shouldn't use those internal state variables in the shader? Or there is another way to initial it in the C code?

I would like to write shader code which cross platform friendly, and be able to run on OpenGL, OpenGL ES and WebGL without much modification.

Comment: Much the same way that all of the functions you mentioned are deprecated, so are `gl_NormalMatrix`, `gl_Vertex`, etc. To write a modern shader that uses them (version >= 150) you have to write `#version ... compatibility` on the first line of your shader. Those things are all replaced with user-defined uniforms and vertex attributes in modern GLSL. I think you may be better off finding a tutorial that teaches OpenGL 3 and forgetting about all that other stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but how will it works with the compatibility? If a old shader has been used, and those GL matrix didn't get set from the code, the shader will not work at all even with the `#version` macro define in the shader, am I understand correctly?

Comment: Right, you have to have a compatibility profile in addition to a shader with `compatibility`. I was no suggesting that as a solution, actually. Because you want to write shaders that are portable across WebGL, ES and desktop GL, you will need to learn and stick to the syntax of GLSL 1.20, but you also need to avoid those variables mentioned before. ES 2.0+ does not support any of those deprecated functions or variables either.

Comment: As a side note: you don't need a Begin/End block if you just want to change the current normal vector. It will work outside of the block as well. It is still deprected, of course, and you shouldn't really use any of that stuff.